# Does Enumerable.Concat always append at the end of the first collection?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, concatenation

Does Enumerable.Concat always append at the end of the first collection?

Example:

```
object someObject = new object();
List<object> listA = new List<object>();
listA.Add(new int());
object item = listA.Concat(new object[] { (object)new float() }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it guaranteed that the `item` will be `int` not `float` after `Concat` on every use? That means:

```
[0] int
[1] float
```

The MSDN says nothing about element order in resulting collection, however examples show that the order is elements from first collection then elements from second collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Concat` is a LINQ method. That means it's a *query*. It does not create a list or some other kind of collection but a sequence.

So what `Concat` actually does is *combining* the two source sequences. When you iterate through the result of `Concat` you first iterate through the first sequence and then through the second sequence. The sequence are thereby never changed.

So, yes

> the item will be `int` not `float` after Concat on every use

---

> The MSDN says nothing about element order

Well it [*does* say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat)

> Concatenates two sequences.

And `to concatenate` means to put one *after* the other, not to mix them up.

---

From the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c0a66e386e37265):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(first, second);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element;
}
```

So you see the two consecutive `foreach` will first yield the elements of the first sequence, then the element of the second sequence.